# Href link followed by onclick events when we press a button

Tags: javascript, html

Presently I have a button which will open a popup and it also pass some parameters(like id,name) in the same page.But now i want to open a welcome page(href link) and there it should the popup page with that id and name what i have passed.My onclick event is a javascript code which will open a popup.I have used something like this

Comment: And this question has nothing to do with php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done in several ways. One simple way is:-

1. Redirect the user to your welcome page when `onclick` is fired.
2. At the same time of redirection, pass the information u want to show in the popup as get parameters to the welcome page.
3. Once the welcome page is loaded, check whether the particular get variables are set. If they are set, show a popup window in that page with the information passed via GET.